# Query in two browser at the same time gives the resultSet of Brow1 in Brow2

Tags: jakarta-ee, synchronization, resultset, thread-synchronization

I am logging into an JavaEE Web application in two different browsers(Brow1 and Brow2) using the **same user login credential** and connecting the **same DB**.
After logging in I am executing a query from Java to get a excel file in resultSet. If I trigger the query in both the browser at the same time, I am getting the resultSet of Brow1 in Brow2 and while the Brow1 one throws a null exception error.

When analyzing the logger I found that brow1 and brow2 have different session Id.
I have also tried synchronizing but that is not an efficient way and takes more time.

Have I missed anything. Is there any other way to fix this issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use different browsers; different sessions are created on server. Though if you had been using different tabs on same browser ; all those tabs share same session because all those tabes share same browser cache where cookies are stored.

Independent requests creates independent threads on Web Server and are handled independently w.r.t. app server. So, now it comes down to application layer how these two independent threads are handled if they are trying to access same data. If you could add what exactly you do ; I can think of what might be going wrong; but we need to fix it at application level.

Comment: I am opening the application in two different browser, and in each browser I am requesting two different reports. The report that should be given to browser one is given to second browser.

Comment: I understand that from your original question; and I mentioned that more details are needed as to how those reports are generated on server.

Comment: Sorry, Initially all the report templates will be there in the DB as a blob object. I will be running the report based on the geography in which it will give the corresponding values of that particular location. 
A separate folders will be created for each browser sessions. Initially the report Template will be downloaded inside the server folder from DB. The report template will have only the variable IDs not the values.

Comment: Then I will pass all the Variable IDs in and get its result set. After getting the resultSet it will be replace the variable Id with values in an instance and finally store the instance inside the Excel sheet.

Comment: See if both folders are getting created correctly or not and if report is there in those folders . Both reports should be identical.